# Draw string over cells after CellPainting event in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, merge

I am implementing this cell painting event for merging duplicate rows in my DataGridView.

```
    private void dataGrid_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
        if (e.RowIndex < 1 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)       return;
        if (IsTheSameCellValue(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex))
        {
            e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
        }
        else
        {
            e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = dataGrid.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Top;
        }
    }

    private void dataGrid_CellFormatting(object sender, 
                                                DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == 0)
            return;
        if (IsTheSameCellValue(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex))
        {
            e.Value = "";
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
    bool IsTheSameCellValue(int column, int row)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell1 = currentDatagrid[column, row];
        DataGridViewCell cell2 = currentDatagrid[column, row - 1];
        if (cell1.Value == null || cell2.Value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return cell1.Value.ToString() == cell2.Value.ToString();
    }
```

The code above merges cells, and I have a seperate code when each cell's backcolor was being changed too. Now, I like to write text over the merged cells as a through this code:

```
    public void MergeCells()
    {

        string subjForDict = renamingSubjects(takenSubj[0]);

        Graphics graph = dataGrid.CreateGraphics();


        Rectangle CellRect1 = dataGrid.GetCellDisplayRectangle(dataGrid.Columns[selectedSubject0].Index, rowNum, true);
        Rectangle CellRect2 = dataGrid.GetCellDisplayRectangle(dataGrid.Columns[selectedSubject0].Index, rowNum + rowLength - 1, true);

        int rectHeight = 0;
        string MergedRows = String.Empty;

        for (int x = rowNum + 2; x <= rowNum + (rowLength + 1); x++)
        {
            rectHeight += dataGrid.GetCellDisplayRectangle(dataGrid.Columns[selectedSubject0].Index, x, true).Height;

        }

        Rectangle newCell = new Rectangle(CellRect1.X, CellRect1.Y, CellRect1.Width, rectHeight);

        graph.DrawString("SUBJECT:", dataGrid.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Century Gothic", 8F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), newCell.X + newCell.Width / 11, newCell.Y + newCell.Height / 10);
        graph.DrawString("ENGLISH", dataGrid.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Century Gothic", 8F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), newCell.X + newCell.Width / 11, newCell.Y + newCell.Height / 2);



    }
```

The problem is that the String drawn using the MergeCells method when I call it is being overwritten by the cell painting event. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you are using this Graphics object: `Graphics graph = dataGrid.CreateGraphics();` so the results will not persist..

Instead of using this `Graphics` object you need to draw stuff that is not within the cell bounds in the `Paint` event..:

```
private void dataGrid_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    MergeCells(e.Graphics);
}
```

And change your `Merge` method to use the correct `Graphics` object, maybe like this:

```
public void MergeCells(Graphics graph)
{
    string subjForDict = renamingSubjects(takenSubj[0]);

    int cellIndex = 
        dataGrid.GetCellDisplayRectangle(dataGrid.Columns[selectedSubject0].Index;
    Rectangle CellRect1 = dataGrid.GetCellDisplayRectangle(cellIndex, rowNum, true);
    Rectangle CellRect2 = dataGrid.GetCellDisplayRectangle(cellIndex, 
                                                           rowNum + rowLength - 1, true);

    int rectHeight = 0;
    string MergedRows = String.Empty;

    for (int x = rowNum + 2; x <= rowNum + (rowLength + 1); x++)
    {
        rectHeight += dataGrid.GetCellDisplayRectangle(cellIndex, x, true).Height;

    }

    Rectangle newCell = new Rectangle(CellRect1.X, CellRect1.Y,
                                      CellRect1.Width, rectHeight);

    using (Font font=new Font("Century Gothic", 8F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
    {      
        int px = newCell.X + newCell.Width / 11;
        graph.DrawString("SUBJECT:", font, brush, px, newCell.Y + newCell.Height / 10);
        graph.DrawString("ENGLISH", font, brush, px, newCell.Y + newCell.Height / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you the code worked just fine. However, do you have any idea on how to draw the string permanently in particular positions? For example, I used the DrawString method for row 2. Now I would merge another set of data at row 6. Can I write another string there, leaving the first one unaffected?

Comment: All drawing must be provided with the data, incuding the string and positions etc.. - So yo will need to have a suitable data structure to do so. Maybe some sort of List and then loop over it in the MergeCells function..

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I'll try it.